# How can i convert a string in a column to row in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do i convert this

```
"ifmanwas"
"meanttos"
"tayonthe"
"groundgo"
"dwouldha"
"vegivenu"
"sroots
```

into this

`"imtgdvsfearwermayoogoanouuiontnnlvtwttddesaohghnsseoau"` in javascript

I know array.forEach should work, Just can not figure out it will work

Comment: are the strings in an array?

Comment: What's the structure? Are these separate strings or the elements of an array ?

Answer (score 0):

Recursion allows us to express an elegant solution -

```js
const strings = 
  [ "ifmanwas"
  , "meanttos"
  , "tayonthe"
  , "groundgo"
  , "dwouldha"
  , "vegivenu"
  , "sroots"
  ]
  
const combine = (s = "", ...more) =>
{ if (more.length === 0)
    return s
  
  if (s.length === 0)
    return combine (...more)
    
  else
    return s[0] + combine (...more, s.substr(1))
}
    
const result =
  combine (...strings)
  
console.log(result)
// imtgdvsfearwermayoogoanouuiontnnlvtwttddesaohghnsseoau
```

Answer (score 0):

## Using Ramda.js makes this easy to do.

```js
const strings = [ 
  "ifmanwas", 
  "meanttos", 
  "tayonthe", 
  "groundgo", 
  "dwouldha", 
  "vegivenu", 
  "sroots", 
]

const transposeStrings = 
  R.pipe(R.transpose, R.flatten, R.join(""))

console.log(transposeStrings(strings))
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ramda@latest/dist/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const strings = [ 
  "ifmanwas", 
  "meanttos", 
  "tayonthe", 
  "groundgo", 
  "dwouldha", 
  "vegivenu", 
  "sroots", 
];
var final = "";

strings.forEach(myFunction);

function myFunction(item, index) {
  final += item;
}

console.log(final);
```

Comment: Hi, your answer is incorrect. The result should be `imtgdvsfearwermayoogoanouuiontnnlvtwttddesaohghnsseoau`. It does not concatenate all strings. It takes the `i` character of all strings, then concatenates them into a new string `imtgdvs`, then concatenates all new strings.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use `for loop` to approach this question.

```js
const array = [ 
  "ifmanwas", 
  "meanttos", 
  "tayonthe", 
  "groundgo", 
  "dwouldha", 
  "vegivenu", 
  "roots", 
];

const newArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
        if (!newArray[j]) newArray[j] = "";
        
        newArray[j] += array[i][j];
    }
}

const result = newArray.join('');

console.log(result); // imtgdvsfearwermayoogoanouuiontnnlvtwttddesaohghnsseoau
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
const data = ["ifmanwas", "meanttos", "tayonthe", "groundgo", "dwouldha", "vegivenu", "sroots"];

const getElement = (i)=>data.map(res=>res.slice(i, i + 1)).join('')
const maxElemnt =Math.max(...data.map(res=>res.length));
const result = Array.from(Array(maxElemnt).keys()).map(r=>getElement(r)).join('');

console.log(result);
```